# Converting from Fahrenheit to celsius

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What temperature (in $^\circ C$) is $180^\circ F$ lower than $100^\circ C$?

---

can someone explain why the answer to this question is "$0^\circ$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways you could address the question.  You could convert the initial $100$ Celsius to Fahrenheit by using the expression

$$
F = 32 + \frac95 C
$$

giving us $212$ Fahrenheit.  $180$ Fahrenheit lower than that is $32$ Fahrenheit, which we can convert back to Celsius using the inverse of the expression above:

$$
C = \frac59 (F-32)
$$

yielding $0$ Celsius.

---

Alternatively, you can recognize that each Celsius degree is worth $9/5 = 1.8$ Fahrenheit degrees, so $180$ Fahrenheit degrees is $100$ Celsius degrees, and $100$ Celsius less than $100$ Celsius is $0$ Celsius.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a matter of how the two scales are defined.  Celsius was chosen to use 0 for the freezing point of water and 100 for its boiling point.  The motivation of Fahrenheit was a bit more complex but it was chosen that the freezing and boiling points of water be 180 apart (like a half circle).  This caused the freezing point to be set at 32 and boiling at 212.  So, 180F below boiling is freezing which is 0C.